# In Javascript, to which object does a `this` keyword inside an arrow function listener point?

Tags: javascript, this, listener, web-component, arrow-functions

The code below creates a listener for an `onchange` event in a html element inside a web component. It uses an arrow function. Inside this function, I used the `this` keyword to refer to the component object (of type `EulInstance`).

```
class EulInstance extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.value = "Hi!";
    }
    ...
    async render() {
        ...
        document.getElementById(selectId).onchange = evt => {
            console.log("this:", this);
            console.log("this.value:", this.value);
        };
   }
}
```

But `this` points to another object. In the console, I get:

```
this: 
+ <eul-instance edit="true" language="pt" types="[&quot;http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Provider&quot; ..."
...
</div></eul-instance>
this.value: undefined
```

To which object is `this` pointing? It has the html text of the `EulInstance` web component but not its fields.

The `this` keyword behavior in the new ECMAScript 6 arrow functions is different from older anonymous functions (using `function(x) {...}`). My question is different from [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback). This older question says that "ECMAScript 6 introduces arrow functions, which can be thought of as lambda functions. They don't have their own this binding. Instead, this is looked up in scope just like a normal variable.". That being correct, the variable `that` and `this`, in the code bellow, should both point to an EulInstance object, but `this` doesn't.

```
...
    async render() {
        ...
        const that = this;
        document.getElementById(selectId).onchange = evt => {
            console.log("this:", this);
            console.log("this.value:", this.value);
            console.log(that === this); // Had to be true
        };
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions take the context (aka `this`) from their parent, so `this` inside the arrow function will be the same as the `this` inside the `render()` function. However that doesn't necessarily have to be an EulInstance:

```
 const fn = (new EulInstance()).render;
 fn(); // calls render with "this" being undefined
```

So you should check how you call `render()` ...

Comment: The `render` function is called by the `connectedCallback` method: Invoked each time the custom element is appended into a document-connected element. This will happen each time the node is moved and may happen before the element's contents have been fully parsed. To which object is `this` pointing? Any idea?